# having problem displaying divider in my layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am trying to add a horizontal divider to my current layout but for some reason the divider is not appearing.

below is my code i tried

```
 return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Text('Total Outstanding', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child:  Text('\$345.55',textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green,)),
                ),

              ])),
          VerticalDivider( width: 0.0, indent: 0.0, color: black),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Column(children: [
                Text('Total Received', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child:   Text('\$1806.50',textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                ),

              ],
              )
          ),Divider(color: Colors.black54),
        ],
    );
```

i am expecting Divider(color: Colors.black54), in my code will draw the divider.  see the picture below.  the red line i drew should be where the divider should appear.  can someone help me modify my code so that the horizontal divider can appear where the red line is?  also there should be some padding on the start of the screen and the end of the screen. thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Wrap your `Row` inside `Column` and use `Divider` as 2nd children of `Column`, first being `Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 56,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Total Outstanding',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child: Text('\$345.55',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          VerticalDivider(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Total Received',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child: Text('\$1806.50', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 12),
    Container(height: 2, color: Colors.black54),
  ],
),
```

Comment: thanks CopsonRoad.  this is very good. i have a couple of questions.  you change VerticalDivider( width: 0.0, indent: 0.0, color: black) for a container.  when i change your code to use vertical divider instead of container, the divider doesnt appear. is there any reason why i cannot use verticaldivider?   the other question is the thickness of the horizontal divider is too thin.  i tried increasing height but not good. how can i make it thicker?

Comment: I have updated the code, `VerticalDivider` is working now along with thicker horizontal divider.

Comment: thanks CopsonRoad.  What i meant was why i cannot use both verticaldivider and divider together but instead you are using verticaldivider and then a container at the end.  if i use verticaldivider and then divider at the end, the vertical divider doesnt appear.

Comment: You can use normal `Divider` at the end but the `height` parameter in Divider isn't the one you are thinking of, it simply increases the `height` of the view and not the `Divider`, just to keep aligned Material design guidelines. You need to use `Container` if you plan to increase thickness.

Comment: And `VerticalDivider` only works with horizontal widgets like `Row` or horizontal `ListView`, and in order to see it on screen, the row needs to have a bounded height, which is why I used `SizedBox(height: 56)`, so the bottom line is you either follow everything according to Material Design (`Divider` has fixed height of `1` dp) or you just have your own ways (`Container` in this case), you can't combine both approaches.